# How to make Werkzeug GET requests log as INFO

Tags: python, flask, logging, gunicorn, werkzeug

I have a Flask API running through gunicorn and I have to keep log level set to DEBUG because I want to see HTTP requests on every endpoint like this:

```
[2022-12-01 15:26:19 -0300] [7833] [DEBUG] GET /query/sample1
[2022-12-01 15:26:26 -0300] [7833] [DEBUG] GET /query/sample2
```

The problem is that quite often Werkzeug logs "Closing connection" messages, flooding my EFK stack log stream:

```
[2022-12-01 15:26:19 -0300] [7833] [DEBUG] GET /query/sample1
[2022-12-01 15:26:26 -0300] [7833] [DEBUG] GET /query/sample2
[2022-12-01 15:26:26 -0300] [5476] [DEBUG] Closing connection. 
[2022-12-01 15:26:27 -0300] [5479] [DEBUG] Closing connection.
```

I know that I can make my own Logger, but I want to separate the HTTP request logs of Werkzeug into INFO messages and keep other details as DEBUG messages. Is there a way to do this?